# pgadmin - Instance * is not persisted on ubuntu

Tags: pgadmin

I have installed pgadmin on ubuntu 20.04.6 and am getting this message when trying to setup a server.

Instance * is not persisted

I see a similar post about this for windows and the solution was to delete files in appdata/roaming profile. Does anyone know the equivalent in ubuntu?